# Microsoft Graph REST API: Unable to access status of long-running-actions

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am attempting to get the status of a long-running-action in Microsoft Graph REST API. I am specifically doing a POST to "driveItem: copy"

```
POST /sites/{siteId}/drive/items/{itemId}/copy
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-copy?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

I am able to make this POST successfully, but since it's a long-running process, it takes longer to complete and my process code moves on to request the freshly copied drive item - but it doesn't exist yet.

The guidance specifies to make a GET request to the URI given in the response to obtain the current status:

```
GET https://api.onedrive.com/monitor/4A3407B5-88FC-4504-8B21-0AABD3412717
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/long-running-actions-overview?tabs=http

When I do this, I get a 401: "Unauthorized" response code. I've tried it both with and without my auth token. I am authenticating as an App with a secret through Azure Entra ID. I have all these permissions:

[image]

It says at the bottom of the page "Working with long running actions (beta)" that "The same permissions that are required to perform a long running action are also required to query the status of a long running action." What are those exactly? I managed to find this link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/richlongrunningoperation-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

It only specifies having Sites.Read.All, which as you can see I have. I did notice this mentioned in Graph API documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/lists-and-libraries/401-error-when-using-graph-api-to-access-data

Not sure if that has anything to do with this. Any ideas?

Here is some of my code:

```
...
// my request to copy: (succeeds)
var copyResponseMessage = await _httpClient.SendAsync(copyRequestMessage);
if (copyResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    string uri = copyResponseMessage.Headers.Location?.AbsoluteUri;
    // uri: https://[ourTenant].sharepoint.com/sites/[ourSiteName]/_api/v2.1/drive/operations/[operationId]
    var statusRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);
    var statusResponseMessage = await _httpClient.SendAsync(statusRequestMessage);
    
    // results in: statusResponseMessage.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized
}
...
```

UPDATE: (3/18/24)

I have come to the conclusion that various Graph API endpoints that are in beta (like the long-running-actions endpoint) are unreliable and should not be used in production.